# Produce sparse pairwise distance matrix python avoiding memory error

Tags: python, scipy, sparse-matrix, distance-matrix

I have some geospatial data and I am trying to produce pairwise haversine distances between points. Unfortunately, there are around 50k data points, which will produce a 50000x50000 distance matrix. Since this distance matrix is symmetric, I was thinking that this matrix could be sparse. I would like to be able to produce a sparse matrix straight from the distance computation, so I don't get memory errors. Here is my code so far:

```
def convert_to_arrays(df1, df2):
    d1 = np.array(df1[['x','y']].values.tolist())
    d2 = np.array(df2[['x','y']].values.tolist())
    return d1,d2

def haversine(data1, data2):
    data1 = np.deg2rad(data1)                     
    data2 = np.deg2rad(data2)                     

    lat1 = data1[:,0]                     
    lng1 = data1[:,1]         

    lat2 = data2[:,0]                     
    lng2 = data2[:,1]         

    diff_lat = lat1[:,None] - lat2
    diff_lng = lng1[:,None] - lng2
    d = np.sin(diff_lat/2)**2 + np.cos(lat1[:,None])*np.cos(lat2) * np.sin(diff_lng/2)**2
    return 2 * 6371 * np.arcsin(np.sqrt(d))

dist = haversine(*convert_to_arrays(df, df))
```

Where `df` is a pandas data frame with columns 'x' and 'y'. When I run this code with around 50k points, I get a memory error:

```
MemoryError: Unable to allocate 19.3 GiB for an array with shape (50893, 50893) and data type float64
```

Is there a way to ensure that the calculation is performed with a (lower or upper triangular) sparse matrix as the intended output?

Comment: The size of the array is too big.

Comment: You can create sparse matrices of this size with float32 precision. For example, `A = scipy.sparse.csr_matrix((50893,50893), dtype=np.float32).toarray()`. I want to be able to compute a sparse lower triangular distance matrix from the start without having to compute a dense matrix first.

Comment: I don't know of any sparse data structure that is more efficient than a standard float array when the sparsity is 50% (which a triangular distance matrix will be).

Comment: @CJR, `scipy.distance` uses a compressed distance matrix representation for this. Basically, you're just storing a 1d array of distances where entries correspond to `[dist(x[0], x[1]), dist(x[0], x[2]), ..., dist(x[0], x[n]), dist(x[1], x[2]), dist(x[1], x[3]), ..., dist(x[n-1], x[n])]`. @CopyOfA, I don't believe `scipy` has any sparse matrix format that does what you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way I found to accomplish this was pretty brute force; if you have a more elegant solution please post it. Essentially, I take the points from the first data frame in chunks and compute pairwise distances with all the points in the second data frame, yielding an Nx50893 array. Then I convert this array to a sparse lower triangular matrix. Finally, I compute the next chunk, convert to lower triangular and stack these arrays.

```
def haversine(data1, data2):
    data1 = np.deg2rad(data1)                     
    data2 = np.deg2rad(data2)                     

    lat1 = data1[:,0]                     
    lng1 = data1[:,1]         

    lat2 = data2[:,0]                     
    lng2 = data2[:,1]         

    #chunk it out 
    N = 2000 #chunk size
    start = 0
    end = N
    #First iteration
    diff_lat = lat1[:N,None] - lat2
    diff_lng = lng1[start:end,None] - lng2()
    d = np.sin(diff_lat/2)**2 + np.cos(lat1[start:end,None])*np.cos(lat2) * np.sin(diff_lng/2)**2
    D = scipy.sparse.tril((2 * 6378137 * np.arcsin(np.sqrt(d))).astype(np.float32))
    start = end
    end += N
    L = len(lat1) - end
    #A bunch more iterations
    while L>0:
        diff_lat = lat1[start:end,None] - lat2
        diff_lng = lng1[start:end,None] - lng2
        d = np.sin(diff_lat/2)**2 + np.cos(lat1[start:end,None])*np.cos(lat2) * np.sin(diff_lng/2)**2
        d = scipy.sparse.tril((2 * 6378137 * np.arcsin(np.sqrt(d))).astype(np.float32))
        D = scipy.sparse.vstack([D,d])
        start = end
        end += N
        L = len(lat1) - end
    #Last iteration    
    diff_lat = lat1[start:,None] - lat2
    diff_lng = lng1[start:,None] - lng2
    d = np.sin(diff_lat/2)**2 + np.cos(lat1[start:,None])*np.cos(lat2) * np.sin(diff_lng/2)**2
    d = scipy.sparse.tril((2 * 6378137 * np.arcsin(np.sqrt(d))).astype(np.float32))
    D = scipy.sparse.vstack([D,d])
        
    return D

dist = haversine(*convert_to_arrays(df, df)
```